# Unsigned char out of bounds for value 247?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, char, unsigned-char

I’m trying to cast the value 247 to a char in C++ (Visual Studio).
I’m getting a Debug Assertion Failed error, saying unsigned(c+1) should be less than or equal to 256. I don’t understand where this is coming from since the value 247 falls in that range.

Comment: When you have a question about code please include a [mcve] of that code in the question

Comment: Also, this will depend on the `/J` switch - `char` can be signed or unsigned in Visual Stduio. Do you use the `/J` switch? (we can't see that from just the example)

Comment: I doubt that your casting is causing the assertion.

Comment: Based on the description of the problem and the code provide, I speculatively surmise there is a bug in the code.

Comment: 247 falls in the range of an `unsigned char`, not in the range of a `char`.

Answer (score -2):

`unsigned char` range is 0 .. 255
`char` range is -128 to 127

Comment: That's not right. `signed char` range is -128 to 127; `char` range is implementation-defined. (Strictly speaking, even that's not right: the implementation is free to use larger ranges. But nobody does.)

Comment: We're looking at Microsoft C++ compiler in Visual Studio here, in which case it uses a single octet (byte) for a char and it is signed by default unless the compiler switch `/J` is used.

Comment: Then you should make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Why - when its stated the question?